# Connect to Milter service unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory

Tags: postfix, email-server, socket, opendkim

I've just been moving a postfix mail server to a different box, and I'm having trouble getting postfix to talk opendkim via a unix socket. The opendkim socket is located at `/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock`:

```
srwxrwxr-x 1 opendkim opendkim 0 Aug 14 15:11 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock=
```

....but postfix can't see it. Here's a line from `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Aug 14 15:13:04 new postfix/smtpd[23954]: warning: connect to Milter service unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory
```

Here is the line from my `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:11444 unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is causing the problem? I have googled around a bit, but I can't find any solutions that work.

**Update:** I'm using Postfix `3.1.0-3`. Here's my `uname -a`:

```
Linux starbeamrainbowlabs.com 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #7 SMP Wed Jan 27 18:05:09 CET 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Is that trailing `=` in your `ls` output  a typo in your post or the actual name of the socket?  Because `opendkim.sock=` is indeed not `opendkim.sock`

Comment: @HBruijn That trailing `=` is actually an `ls` indicator. It doesn't actually exist in the filename: http://imgur.com/a/PdYY0

Comment: Ah! Never seen that ls option before, you learn something new every day :)

Comment: @HBruijn I use `alias ll='ls -hAtFl'
alias la='ls -hA'
alias l='ls -htFl`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to set the socket file in spool dir of postfix, e.g:

`/var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim`

After changing that, you might see problem about permission, then just change group owner of that dir to postfix and it will work.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74491/22454

Comment: Yep, it turns out that postfix was treating the `/var/spool/postfix` directory as the root directory. Putting it in there solved the problem :-)

Comment: To clarify, have the postfix conf just look for /var/run/opendkim, but in opendikm.conf you want to point to the full path of /var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim

Comment: to clarify it unclear and doesn't help at all. unfortunately, i cant downvote